# possible to replace top of html document using frames?

Tags: html

I'm working with a partner site that does not have bandwidth to make customizations on their end.

I would like to use there site in a frame, under another frame w/ an updated header and logo that will be hosted on my site...

Is there a way I can make the 2nd frame start about an inch down on the target html page so as to not show both my new frame based header, and the original header on the site?

I'm guessing the way to do this is to hide the real scroll-bar in the frame, and replace it with a javascript controlled scroll-bar that lives in the outer-frame?

Comment: Is the header and logo just images? On the partner's site you can just call the absolute path to the images on your server from their page. If I understand what you are saying.

Comment: I can't edit the code of the partner site... I am looking to instead place their site inside of a frame on my local site, and automatically scroll down past the sub-frames header.

Comment: why not create your site, and replicate their header? you can use the absolute path of their logo. surely, they should use the same path for their logo, even if they updated it. unless the header has something else that you dont have control, like say content perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say, is that I want to keep everything served from the remote site EXCEPT the header which should be local to my site...  So basically I want to serve their page, but with my header and logo on top instead of their header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mask for the iframe. Make the iframe as big as the content you would like to display, then hide the top behind a div's boundaries like so.

```
<style>
#iframe-container
{
    top : -300px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 10000px;
    position : relative;
}

#iframe
{
    position : absolute;
    top : -300px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
</style>

<div id="iframe-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.yourpartner.com" id="iframe-container" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  However I don't know the length of the document (it changes regularly)... any way arround needing to know the length beforehand?

Comment: no... there really isn't ... would you happen to be using php?

Comment: you could try screen scraping. `echo file_get_contents('http://yourpartnersdomain.com');` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: I have this partially working... I set the height way to big, which is fine because if the user keeps scrolling they just see black...  
The negative number for the top position doesn't work for me though.

Comment: It's working now... I just added the "top" attribute to #iframe-container, and updated your answer to show the change.